# One word for the moment one remembers a dream?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a noun that describes the moment one remembers a dream in its entirety while lucid. Not *déjà vu*, but that moment when the memories come flooding in, and one understands that one is remembering a dream.

Comment: this would be like anagnorisis, but in the lucid world as referring to the realization of the loss of self.

Comment: A *madeleine* moment.

Comment: Niels Bohr had an **epiphany** in his dream about  the atom structure.

Comment: @HotLicks  I always thought "a madeleine moment" referred to childhood memories.

Comment: You could coin _somnamnesis_ (from Latin _somnium_ dream) or _oneiromnesis_ (from Greek _óneiro_ dream) if you follow the word [_anamnesis_](https://www.etymonline.com/word/anamnesis).

Comment: @Centaurus - To me it means a sensory input which triggers the recall some memory.  Not necessarily a dream, though.

Comment: Interestingly, there ain't one. Idiomatically, we just say that we *recalled a dream*, or, had *a recollection of a dream*. I have my own expression: *"My subconscious filter is leaking again"*.

Comment: A flashback, no matter it did not really happen

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not a noun, but a *topos*: *[a Proustian moment](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/books/authors/simon-heffer-proust-madeleine-wagner/)* or *madeleine moment*, in reference to Proust's famous experience when he dipped a [madeleine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeleine_(cake)) into a cup of tea.

In principle that should be in reference to a real experience. We could argue, however, that even though the content of the dream was not real, the *experience* of the dream was real.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way to describe **the moment one remembers a dream in its entirety while lucid** is [***anamnesis***](https://www.etymonline.com/word/anamnesis), which means the calling back of a memory once completely forgotten.

My Webster's dictionary (c.1959) says that it's from the Greek, *anamnesis*, meaning a calling to mind (again) or recalling of a forgotten memory; with synonyms being [*a recollection*](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/anamnesis), or *a remembering*. It also provides the two most commonly understood definitions:

> 1. (*noun*) a remembering, especially of a supposed life before this life. [Referring to Platonic Philosophy].
> 2. (*noun*) in medicine, the history of a particular case of disease. [Referring to a patient's testimony given to the consulting physician].

Beyond the standard dictionary definitions, art scholars also use the word when speaking of [artistic anamnesis](https://books.google.com/books?id=-OSsCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT101&dq=dream%20anamnesis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ9a2ttODZAhVY3GMKHV8CDjUQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=dream%20anamnesis&f=false), which I gather is the mental process by which great painters / artists interpret their unique visions / ideas onto the canvas or other media:

> Lyotard can thus write: "the language of the dream seems to be nothing more nor less than the language of art."
>
> **Anamnesis** is to be understood as one of the operators that allow Lyotard to *link* psychoanalysis and art.

There is also a type of [anamnesis](https://www.google.com/search?q=anamnesis%20and%20the%20eucharist&rlz=1C1PRFI_enUS771US771&oq=anamnesis%20and%20the%20eucharist&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.6785j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) associated with the ritual religious experience of the [Eucharist](https://books.google.com/books/about/Anamnesis_and_the_Eucharist.html?id=-xDmEX6HBwsC), which I nearly forgot to mention.

However, it is interesting that [psychologists](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C10&q=anamnesis%20dream%20recall&btnG=) also use the exact same word when discussing the recollection of both repressed memories and [**forgotten dreams**](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/9236/what-did-jungs-patient-find-out). One study found that in the case of **dreams** memories are not *emotionally repressed*, as with traumatic amnesia. Instead, the [theory](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f1af/886bfac2ee058ddaf1a6fb61dabe08e19b08.pdf) is that some kind of chemical brain process *physiologically suppresses* dreams, because of their subconscious nature, from entering conscious thought -- for some mysterious reason (they seem to suggest that it may be to prevent problems distinguishing between reality and fantasy or hallucinations).

And that's why dreams are so difficult to recall.

> Finally, the new theory does not deny meaning to *dreams*, but it does
> suggest 1) **a more direct route to their acquisition than**
> ***anamnesis*** via free association, since *dream origins are
> in basic physiological processes* and not in disguised
> wishes...

- I often experience **anamnesis**; yet every time it happens, it takes me by surprise.